# OpenVPN is only able to connect to 3 ports: 80, 8080 and 443

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openvpn

I installed OpenVPN 2.3.7 and connect to a server via SSH.
The config file of OpenVPN uses UDP port 1195.
Then I have installed nginx and tried to connect to different ports. I realized that I am only able to connect to 3 port 80, 8080 and 443 to the server, other ports were not able to connect although `ufw` has been disabled.
The server run Ubuntu 18.04 and nginx 1.14.0.
Hope for your help. Thanks!

Comment: You question is a little vague: `OpenVPN` creates a tunnel using port 1195. You use this tunnel to connect through `ssh`? What are the results of running `netstat -tlnp` and `iptables -nvL`?

Comment: Sounds like there is a firewall for the organisation limiting traffic.